# SAP GUI Client integration with classic ASP ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: asp-classic, sap-gui, sap-erp

We have a classic ASP site that is hosted on windows server 2003 (32 bit). It has an early version of SAP GUI client installed and from within the asp pages we hook into SAP R4 with a standard call to `Set Myobj = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")`, this all works.

We are now porting the app to Windows Server 2012 and we have had to install SAP GUI client version 7 (the earlier client wouldn't install), when the app hits the above line I receive this error message:

> ActiveX component can't create object

Can I just install the DLL's from the windows Server 2003 and use RegSVR32 to register them?

If yes what dll's do I need to copy and is there an order to register them?

Or do I have to do something completely different?

Comment: No idea what is SAP R4. Do you mean release 4? There are only R/3 (version 4 ranges from 4.0, to 4.70 including 4.5* and 4.6*) and S/4HANA software.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

CreateObject("SAP.Functions.Unicode")

source - https://blogs.sap.com/2015/09/18/how-to-use-named-references-of-sap-activex-libraries-in-vba-for-easy-programming/

Comment: I've tried that I still get the same issue. If I look through the object browser in VS2010 I don't see any of the Sap ActiveX's. I think they need to be registered, but On the list given in the link there's no entry point when I try to register them, so I'm probably missing the parent ocx/dll somewhere, but I don't know what the parent object is.

Comment: I did find this post, maybe it'll help: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/7859

Comment: I've copied over the files from our windows server 2003 to the windows 2012 server, using regsvr32 against librfc32.dll still gives the same error